# Segmentation Fault In Linked List Append

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

I have been using linked list and I have used the following code for append function which i wrote in a new file and it works perfectly but when I copy it my main code it gives segmentation fault at `while(current->next != null)` . It does not give any warning while compiling so I don't know whats the issue here.

```
// Linked List Node for Reading Comments
struct Node{
    char value;
    struct Node *next;
};

void append(struct Node * headNode, char newElement){
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  //Dynamically Allocating Memory for New Node                   
    struct Node *current = headNode;                     //Creating A Node to traverse the linked list

    newNode->value = newElement;                         //Assigning the values of newNode to the given value
    newNode->next = NULL;                                //Setting next value to be null since its the last node

    if (headNode == NULL){                               //Checking if headnode is empty
        headNode = newNode;                              //Assigning headnode and tailnode to be newnode
    }

    else {                
        while(current->next != NULL){                    //Traversing through the linked list
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;                         //Setting tailnode's next to be newnode   

    }
 
}

void printLinkedList(struct Node* headNode){
    while(headNode != NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"%c",headNode->value);
        headNode = headNode->next;
    }
}
```

If anyone can comment on this please do.

Comment: Remember that in C, function arguments are passed *by value*. That means the value used in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variable. Modifying the local argument variable (like assigning to it) only changes that local variable, not whatever variable or expression that was used in the call. Now think about that in the context of the `headNode` argument for the `append` function, and the assignment to it. And do some research about *emulating **pass by reference** in C*.

Comment: Please provide the (minimal) main code that is necessary to produce such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not allow to add a node to an empty list. If you try and did not initialise your `head` pointer on the calling side, you may get such behavior.

For instance, in `main` you could have:

```
    struct Node* head; // not initialised
    append(head, 'a'); 
    printLinkedList(head);
```

These are then the issues:

- If `head` happens to be not `NULL`, then the `else` block will kick in and the `current` pointer will reference some unintended memory address.
- `append` will not change the `head` variable of `main`. It will only modify a local variable that happens to have a similar name (`headNode`).

To correct, pass the *address* of `head` to the `append` function, and let `append` deal with this accordingly:

```
void append(struct Node ** headNode, char newElement) {
    struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *current = *headNode;
    newNode->value = newElement;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (*headNode == NULL) {
        *headNode = newNode;
    } else {                
        while(current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Note the additional `*` wherever `headNode` occurs. In `main`:

```
    struct Node* head;
    append(&head, 'a');
    printLinkedList(head);
```